# using jquery to find radiobutton groups with no answers

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, radio-button

I've been racking my brain to find a better solution to the following situation.

Imagine a page with a LOT of radiobuttons on it, and then having some custom validation highlighting the groups of radiobuttons that haven't been answered.

example html (with some answers preselected):

```
<input type='radio' name='a' value='1' />
<input type='radio' name='a' value='2' />
<input type='radio' name='a' value='3' />
<input type='radio' name='b' value='1' checked="checked"//>
<input type='radio' name='b' value='2' />
<input type='radio' name='b' value='3' />
<input type='radio' name='c' value='1' />
<input type='radio' name='c' value='2' checked="checked"/>
<input type='radio' name='c' value='3' />
<input type='radio' name='d' value='1' />
<input type='radio' name='d' value='2' />
<input type='radio' name='d' value='3' />
```

I've already written a bit of jQuery that does what i want, but I just know it can be done better/faster/prettier/more efficiently.

```
//select all radiobuttons
var $radios = $("input[type='radio']")
//loop through all the radios that are checked
$($radios+":checked").each(function(){
    //filter out all radios with the current name, and add something to recognize them with
    $($radios).filter("[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']").addClass("checked")
});

//find all radios without the class checked, and highlight them
var $unchecked_radios = $($radios + ":not(.checked)").addClass("highlight");
```

But i'm stuck on how to combine those two, so subtracting the ones that have an answer from the entire population of radios.

(although i suspect there might be a better way to select groups of radiobuttons with the same name)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Regards,
Casper

Comment: Will an object `{a: false, b: true, c: true, d: false}` work for you?

Comment: @salman A, not really, because if i get it back as an jQuery object i can immediately do other stuff with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if can help, here is some code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('input:not(:checked)').each(function() {
            if($('input[name='+$(this).attr('name')+']:checked').size() == 0)
            {
                $(this).addClass('highlight');
            }
        });
    });
```

With this, you only highlight the unchecked radio of groups that don't have any radio checked yet.
Does it fit your need?

Comment: Nice approach! yeah, i think this might work! let me do some profiling to see the actual gain

Comment: In a simple test case (100 radios in 25 groups) this takes 18ms, while my old approach took 25. So not a huge improvement but still quite significant.

Comment: I think there can be a faster code to do the job (in my code there are more loops than needed) but I couldn't find a better solution for now... i'm glad that helped!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
function is_answered(valueName)
{
  var result=$('input[name='+valueName+']:checked').size();
  return result > 0;
}
```

Comment: That would make it a lot easier indeed :-) But unfortunately adding even more elements to my DOM is a bit out of scope for my project. thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $radios = $("input[type='radio']")
//loop through all the radios that are checked
$radios.filter(":checked")
.each(function(){
    //filter out all radios with the current name, and add something to recognize them with
    $($radios).filter("[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']").addClass("checked")
})
.end()
.filter(":not(.checked)").addClass("highlight");
```

Depending on the usecase, this might be nicer:

```
$("input[type='radio']").filter(":not(:checked)").addClass("highlight");
```

But I do not know if you need the "checked" class for something else too.

Comment: Hi Excelian, your first suggestion gives the results i want, and indeed, it is a bit nicer because of it only using one jQuery variable. I'd still like to get rid of the "checked" class, since i don't need it.